# Meaning of the word "Type" in "Reconciliation Tradeoffs" in react reconciliation documentation

Tags: facebook, reactjs

In the [React Documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reconciliation.html#tradeoffs):

> The algorithm will not try to match subtrees of different component types.

The word "type" can often refer to many things. In this case, are they referring to `React.Component` types versus stateless functional component types?